# Facebook Like/Send button dynamically generated not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I dynamically create the Like/Send button, the Div for the fb-root is displaying that the SDK is working, yet the button is not displaying what so ever for some reason.

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
   var _URL = window.location.href ;
 $('.center.pic-container').before('<div class="fb-like" data-href="'+_URL+'" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui" data-action="recommend"></div>');
});
(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

It is wrapped in a doc ready function btw. Any suggestions to the dynamically generated like button? Maybe a set time out or something?

Second Code Tried=

```
$(function() {
   var Sscript = '<script type="text/javascript">';
   var Escript = '</script>';
   var code = Sscript +'(function(d, s, id){var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));'+Escript;
 $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>'+code);
   var add = $('.center.pic-container').children('a').first().attr('href');
   var URL = add.toString();
   var _URL = window.location.host + URL;
 $('.center.pic-container').before('<div class="fb-like" data-href="'+_URL+'" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui" data-action="recommend"></div>');
    });
```

Comment: Are there any script errors visible in the browser console? Any hints as to what the issue is?

Comment: No, that is the issue. And why I am completely clueless to the reason why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: Are you able to use Firebug or the F12 tools in the browser to step through the JavaScript? That usually makes troubleshooting issues like this easier. Perhaps post the entire script and relevent markup/CSS too - the issue might be in something you haven't shared.

Comment: I'm not to sure about that as I've walked through the console in chrome, I've also updated the first post with new code I've tried and still not getting anything. And there isn't anything on there because I can create this with hardcode and it works.

Comment: We both overlooked something very important :D in the js.src line I had to add #xfbml=1 to the url. It is working now thank you though

Comment: oh ok - maybe add that as your own answer to your question then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question, I found out after reviewing each line.

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
  var _URL = window.location.href ;
 $('.center.pic-container').before('<div class="fb-like" data-href="'+_URL+'" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui" data-action="recommend"></div>');
});
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

the `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"` should be this `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"` which grabs the correct XFBML tags needed, if you check the `#fb-root` div and it will append to Iframes.

Hope this helps everyone else.